# Populating WebMatrix SQL Server Compact

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-ce, webmatrix

are there any ways to populate the WebMatrix sql server with some script so that I can test the website better? I need some data on my server. Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ErikEJ's tools to get data from an existing SQL Server (Full) database and script it to fill a SQL Server Compact 4 database: http://erikej.blogspot.com/2010/02/how-to-use-exportsqlce-to-migrate-from.html

Comment: I'm more like looking for a tool that can open the existing "sdf" file and let me execute my pre-generated queries. That would be way faster in case I want to make modifications. Best!

Comment: There are some VS tools planned, but I don't know when they will be ready. ErikEJ produced hos set because of the lack of tooling support for CE 4, as it's so new. There is of course, the Query window in the Database Workspace in WebMatrix.

Answer (score 1):

The sqlcecmd mentioned in the blog does just that (execute pregenerated queries), and I also have made a VS 2010 add-in: http://sqlcetoolbox.codeplex.com